# Negative decimal values truncated when store to oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

When I tried to store the decimal x = -258.9697 to database from EntityFramework, I got exception of "ORA-16550: truncated result". The column of x in the db is NUMBER (7, 4), and it's no problem if I store x as positive decimal value 258.9697.  The exception solved if I increase the scale to, like (10, 4). Anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Oracle provider and version are you on? This sounds like [Bug 28227512](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=2471759.1&id=28227512):

> OracleDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale method of ODP managed driver throws 
>   ORA-16550 error for negative values paassed as the negative sign is 
>   considered while calculating the precision.

If I'm reading it right, it should be fixed in ODP.NET version 19.1 and later.

Comment: Thanks... I'm using an older version